# Injecting screen_on event to make sensors work when screen is off 

Tags: android, events, reflection, sensors

I am trying to make sensors work when screen is off. It is well known bug. And there is no any soution for this on all phones. I have the hypothesis that i can can cheat kernel if I send(inject) screen_on event while actually the screen will be turned off. Do you have any ideas how can i check my hypothesis and inject such event?

Comment: have you tried by acquiring a wakelock?

Comment: of course i have tried. All tried it... only dim and full brightness wake lock helps... but they use battery a lot. Also i  tried  to turn screen on after screen is off an then set brightness  to zero, but it is rise the screen off event and sensors bacome off. Also i tried to unregister and register sensors after screen is off. But is isnt works on sevaral mobile devices (LG and Archos for shure)

Comment: @Brans did you ever manage to get this answered?  Great idea BTW.

Answer (score -5):

Why don't you start a [background service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) that monitors the sensors?

And then send/use the results back to your application's activities.
Your activity will still pause when screen goes off, but you will continue to read the sensor data.

Also a good idea to do the heavy processing the background service as well...

This works great for me.

Comment: It is background service.. it doesn't matter. Sensors are off when screen is off..

Comment: @Brans What do you mean by screen is off? You have some smart battery saver installed like PocketSensor? Or is the screen just locked?